# file_exists and paths that include relative paths ("/../")

Tags: php, file-exists

When I use `file_get_contents` on a path like `/a/path/to/a/../file.php`, it gets the content just fine. If I call `file_exists` first (or `is_file` or `realpath`), the return values indicate that the file does not exist. What seems to be the issue?

---

Edit: Here is some additional information condensed from comments to answers:

- I am running Mac OS X 10.9 with **php 5.5.6**, so **safe mode should not be an issue** [(it was removed in version 5.4)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php)
- I tried **clearing the file cash** by calling `clearstatcache(true, $dir1)`
- The file in question is 362 bytes in size, but **I reproduced this issue with several different files** in a medley of locations.
- `open_basedir` is commented out in the php.ini
- **The file is local** (the first file I tried was in the same directory as the script)
- The issue exists in the command line (phpUnit) and in the browser.
- The permissions on the file in questions are `-rwxrwxrwx` (I sudo-chmod-777ed the file)

This is a code snippet that creates the behavior:

```
$dir1 = '/a/path/to/a/../file.php';
$dir2 = '/a/path/to/file.php';

echo "File content dir1:\n";
echo file_get_contents($dir1);
echo "\ndir1 exists: ".(int)file_exists($dir1);

echo "\n\nFile content dir2:\n";
echo file_get_contents($dir2);
echo "\ndir2 exists: ".(int)file_exists($dir2);
```

the output is:

```
File content dir1:
The actual content of the file. I promise!

dir1 exists: 0

File content dir2:
The actual content of the file. I promise!

dir2 exists: 1
```

Comment: can you post the specific code you're comparing here? `file_exists()` should handle paths like that just fine.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this behavior – I tried both with a relative path and an absolute path both including '..'

Comment: @ whoever voted to close for "not clear what you are asking," please specify what you find unclear, I would love to address your concern.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you have safe mode turned on and are attempting to access a file that PHP would consider unsafe when running in safe mode. [From the manual](https://www.php.net/file_exists):

> Warning
>
> This function returns FALSE for files inaccessible due to safe mode restrictions. However these files still can be included if they are located in safe_mode_include_dir.

**EDIT:** You can also reproduce this behavior if `/a/path/to/a/` is not a real path. For example:

```
<?php

$dir1 = '/realDir/realDir2/filetoinclude.php';
echo "File content dir1:\n";
echo file_get_contents($dir1); // outputs file contents
echo "\ndir1 exists: ".(int)file_exists($dir1); // outputs 1

$dir2 = '/realDir/realDir2/realDir3/../filetoinclude.php';
echo "\n\nFile content dir2:\n";
echo file_get_contents($dir2); // outputs file contents
echo "\ndir2 exists: ".(int)file_exists($dir2); // outputs 1

$dir3 = '/realDir/realDir2/NotARealDirectory/../filetoinclude.php';
echo "\n\nFile content dir3:\n";
echo file_get_contents($dir3); // outputs file contents
echo "\ndir3 exists: ".(int)file_exists($dir3); // outputs 0
```

This is because file_exists needs to traverse the entire path, literally, so it looks for the missing directory and fails. I'm not sure exactly what file_get_contents does that is different, and I can't find much on Google, but it clearly does some parsing of the path that is different from what file_exists does.

Comment: Hmm... Do you have open_basedir set in php.ini?

Comment: Yeah, leave open_basedir turned off -- it would potentially interfere with your code, which is why I asked.

Comment: The results of file_exists are cached. Have you tried just clearing the cache? http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php

Comment: The only other theories I have are file size or permissions problems. How big is the file? Sometimes that can cause a failure because of how *nix `stat` works.

Comment: And this is a local file, not a remote file or symlink, but a real file?

Comment: Much appreciated; I'll keep thinking because this bothers me.

Comment: Okay, I was able to reproduce this, and I'm 99% sure I've got it. Does the full path `/a/path/to/a/` actually exist? For example, if I have a file `/foo/bar/file.php` and a directory `/foo/bar/woot/`, then file_exists works with `/foo/bar/woot/../file.php`, but not with `/foo/bar/someDirectoryThatIsntReal/../file.php`.

Answer (score 1):

I am providing the workaround that I developed with a regex, if others have this same issue. I hate to be using this hack, and I still don't understand why I am having this issue, but hopefully someone will come up with an actual solution.

Before calling `file_exists` I now call this function:

```
function resolve($path) {
    $regex = "/(.?)(\/[^\/]*\/\.\.)(.*)/";
    $result = preg_replace($regex, "$1$3", $path);
    if ($result != $path) {
        $result = resolve($result);
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: `realpath` does not work with non-existing files within the relative path on Unix-like systems. In opposite to Windows, each file within the path must exist.

Comment: You might be misunderstanding the problem I am having. The file exists. A relative path, like the one in my original post, does not get recognized by `realpaht`, `is_file` or `file_exists`. `file_get_contents` successfully retrieves the content though.

Comment: In that case you should at least use a proven algorithm like the [*remove dot segments* algorithm used for URIs](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21424232/53114).